how to change the shape to SearchBar widget in flutter
I want search bar in a rectangle shape, but corner should be slightly rounded. by default its corder are too rounded. anyone can help me to make its corner customisable. Below is the code I tried.
SearchBar(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.search),
                      hintText: "Search by ID, Store name & etc",
                      shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll<OutlinedBorder>(CircleBorder()),
                    ),
                  ),


Use this instead and customize the border radius according to your preferences:
shape: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
  RoundedRectangleBorder()
),

